# nodejs request only able to send 10 requests

Tags: node.js, https, request, node-request

I've created a nodejs program which basically verifies facebook tokens by using the https graph api via an https request as follows:

```
var request=require("request")
request('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,name,gender,picture&access_token='+data.fb_token,function(error,response,body){
    ...
    console.log('request #'+(++reqCount)+' has completed!');
});
```

The problem is that I am only able to make 10 single requests. Any requests made after the 10th never complete (ie, the callback is never called and there is no data sent back). I've tried adding a timeout parameter in a parametrized request to no avail.

Comment: And you're sure you're not just hitting Facebooks rate limiter, they do have one in place.

Comment: You checked for the `error` response and the limit on number of req.

Comment: @adeneo Yeah I'm not hitting the facebook rate limiter as it allows me to immediately send another ten requests if i restart the node application

Comment: @nash_ag I have a small check for the error flag in the callback `if(error){...}` but the problem seems to be that the callback never occurs. What is the limit on the number of requests and how do I set that?

Comment: Maybe you should use async module for sending requests to facebook , try to send requests as sync , Moreover , why are you sending too muck request ? Do you want to get updated informations real-time ?

Comment: @OsmanErdi The nodejs program is running server side as part of a mobile api to verify facebook tokens server side to act as a 'login'. The requests are not made concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that it was a separate bug. I was using a database connection pool and not releasing them.